# Plone 4.1 commenting does not show up on SunBurst theme

Tags: themes, plone

I have Plone 4.1 with plone.app.discussion = 2.1.5 and quintagroup.plonecomments. Also, I have several sites with configured commenting globally on simple page. THe first one works as it should, but another commenting does not show up at all. Moreover, the second one has SunBurst theme and I gues that this theme does not include plone.comments viewlet, because when I used @@manage-viewlets on the first site, it showed it and when I used it on the other one - no sign of plone.comments. How can I enable this viewlet?

Comment: Sounds like plone.app.discussion is not installed on the second site, or it is migrated and missing browserlayer registration. Try reinstalling plone.app.discussion?

Comment: I can't find any other uninstall option than using buildout.

Comment: and that does not help.

Comment: It is weird that, when I installed plone.app.discussion, it works for other sites only.